# Setting value to backend bean

Tags: jsf, parameters, jsf-2.2

There might be many threads with same heading and I almost covered all the questions but couldn't figure out solution to my problem.

1. I have a template - say application.xhtml.
2. in my application.xhtml I have something called as say application.transact which refers to a transact object inside the application bean.
3. in the transact object I have a boolean field agree.
4. in my template I have a panel

```html
<h:panelGroup id="newApplication_agree" layout="block">
    <ui:param name="transact" value="#{application.transact}"/>
    <p:panel toggleable="true">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td width="1%" align="left">
            <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="agree" value="#{application.transact.agree}"
    required="true" requiredMessage="this is a mandatory field">
              <f:validator validatorId="omnifaces.RequiredCheckboxValidator" />
            </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
          </td>
          <td width="95%" align="left" colspan="3"> 
            <h:outputText id="agreeText" value="I agree"/>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </p:panel>
</h:panelGroup>
```

no matter what I tried the value is not getting set to the application.transact.agree

Comment: <h:panelGroup id="newApplication_agree" layout="block">
  <ui:param name="transact" value="#{application.transact}"/>
<p:panel toggleable="true"
<table>
<tr>
<td width="1%" align="left">
<h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="agree" value="#{application.transact.agree}"
required="true" requiredMessage="this is a mandatory field">
<f:validator validatorId="omnifaces.RequiredCheckboxValidator" />
</h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
</td>
 <td width="95%" align="left" colspan="3"> 
<h:outputText id="agreeText" value="I agree"/>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</p:panel>
</h:panelGroup>

Comment: this is the panel i said in point 4. somehow i am not able to put the code in question.

Comment: Do you have errors? What's the scope of your bean?

Comment: You seem to be needing to put the xhtml in a 'html snippet' now... Only way I could get it to work here. And PLEASE create a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out guys. i was placing the  in a wrong place where transact object was unreachable hence, the error.

thanks for your time.